# Substraction within an Ansible space calculation

Tags: ansible

I try to subtract 2 variables in Ansible, but what I get is zero in the result.

```
- name: ansible calculate space
  hosts: pghosts
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

  - name: Check /srv freespace
    shell: df /srv --output\=avail | tail -1
    register: srv_freespace

  - name: Check postgres data dir size
    shell: du -ks /srv/postgresql/data |awk '{  print $1 }'
    register: postgres_data

  - debug:
     msg: "substraction {{ srv_freespace|int - postgres_data|int }}"

  - copy: content="{{ srv_freespace|int - postgres_data|int }}" dest=/tmp/results.txt
```

Comment: It seemes, that I have to append stdout to the variables when caclculating
 msg: "substraction {{ srv_freespace.stdout|int - postgres_data.stdout|int }}"

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the last line to:

```
  - copy: content="{{ srv_freespace.stdout|int - postgres_data.stdout|int }}" dest=/tmp/results.txt
```

**Explanation**: the registered variable is not a string, its a dict. The dict includes several keys like the command name, command start and end time, exit code and other good stuff. The actual value i.e. what is printed to standard output is under the *stdout* key.